# Regex R Extracting multiple string matches

Tags: r, regex

In R, I am looking to parse a succession of log data into categorised events.

I have a vector call regex_text, it's a continuous string (line breaks added for clarity here):

```
21/08/2014 22:58CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing
21/08/2014 23:00EXE_IN.preparing
21/08/2014 23:07CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing
21/08/2014 23:08CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing
21/08/2014 23:12EXE_CO.preparing
21/08/2014 23:28EXE_IN.preparing
21/08/2014 23:29CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing
21/08/2014 23:30CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing
```

and would like to use regex to process the first and last timestamps of each sequences of 'CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing' and place them into this dataframe:

```
          start_ts          stop_ts
1 21/08/2014 22:58 21/08/2014 22:58
          start_ts          stop_ts
2 21/08/2014 23:07 21/08/2014 23:08
          start_ts          stop_ts
3 21/08/2014 23:29 21/08/2014 23:30
```

There could be many repetitions of 'CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing', my example just has two instances with two entries in each.

The code below can be run directly in R and currently outputs a single entry:

```
          start_ts          stop_ts
1 21/08/2014 23:07 21/08/2014 23:30
```

I would like guidance on how to extract two entries, as above

Code:

```
library(stringr)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

eventised_session <- data.frame(start_ts=as.character(),
                                stop_ts=as.character())

regex_text <- "21/08/2014 22:58CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing21/08/2014 23:00EXE_IN.preparing21/08/2014 23:07CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing21/08/2014 23:08CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing21/08/2014 23:12EXE_CO.preparing21/08/2014 23:28EXE_IN.preparing21/08/2014 23:29CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing21/08/2014 23:30CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing"
regex_pattern <- "(\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4}\\s\\d{2}\\:\\d{2})(CONTENT_ACCESS\\.preparing)"


if (grepl(regex_pattern, regex_text, perl=TRUE)) {

  sm <- str_match_all(regex_text, regex_pattern )

  #Get the first and last timestamp in matched sequence
  r_start_ts <- sapply(sm, function(x) x[1, 2])
  r_stop_ts <- sapply(sm, function(x) x[sapply(sm,nrow), sapply(sm, ncol) - 1])

  eventised_session[nrow(eventised_session)+1,] <- c(r_start_ts, r_stop_ts)
  print(eventised_session)
}
```

Comment: Ideally, someone should be able to just copy what you posted and run it. Also, there is no need to post any data generation code unless it is relevant to your question. Just `dput` the data.frame at the point where it is necessary to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Funtboy Posting a link to data files github is often useful. The goal is to provide a self contained example, that hilights the problem you are focused on addressing.

Comment: Can you distill your code relevant to the question to bare minimum? Your question appears to be a regex question. Usually a vector of a few strings and the pattern you're trying to match is all it takes to convey this information. The whole infrastructure around that code may be unnecessary for this particular question.

Comment: what is your goal? what is your expected output? After reading all this stuff, i still do not understand what you want

Comment: Thank you all. Apologies for my crude approach. I will distil my question,

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have added to my question. I hope this brings some clarity.

Comment: @Onyambu, is this a little clearer?

Comment: You even complicated it more. What you are supposed to do is give a few rows of your data, and how you expect it to be in the end stating how you get to the expected result, eg what exactly to extract. That is how you should structure your question. The attempt should come AFTER the two. Your question is tooooo looong one loses focus, and also we cant tell what data you need and what you expect. You don't expect one to read a whole novel to understand what you want. read @RomanLuštrik comment

Comment: Fair point @Onyambu. I have slimmed it down now. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: The truth is you still need to learn [how to create a minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So what is your question? Just delete everything and type:. `I have a vector/list/table/dataframe etc(give your data) and would like to use regex to transform it into (give the expected output) .. I would like to do.. (give logic how to transform..etc). Here is my trial (give what you've tried)` that is the way to go...

Comment: Okay @Onyambu, I have followed your template. I have also added stripped down code that you can run directly in R (with the stringr library installed). Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Now this makes sense. I hope the example you gave captures what you need .. Are you looking for something like `setNames(data.frame(gsub("[a-z].*","",t(matrix(grep("CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing",vec,value=T),2)),T)),c("Start_ts","Stop_ts"))` where `vec` is your vector above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
vec = c("21/08/2014 23:07CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing", "21/08/2014 23:08CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing", "21/08/2014 23:12EXE_CO.preparing", "21/08/2014 23:28EXE_IN.preparing", "21/08/2014 23:29CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing", "21/08/2014 23:30CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing")

setNames(data.frame(gsub("[a-z].*","",t(matrix(grep("CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing",vec,value=T),2)),T)),c("Start_ts","Stop_ts"))
         Start_ts          Stop_ts
1 21/08/2014 23:07 21/08/2014 23:08
2 21/08/2014 23:29 21/08/2014 23:30
```

If you have the `regex_text` as in your code then you could do:

```
regex_text <- "21/08/2014 23:07CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing21/08/2014 23:08CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing21/08/2014 23:12EXE_CO.preparing21/08/2014 23:28EXE_IN.preparing21/08/2014 23:29CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing21/08/2014 23:30CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing"

a = gsub(".*?(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2})CONTENT_ACCESS[.]preparing.*?","\\1\n",regex_text)

setNames(data.frame(matrix( unlist(strsplit(a,"\n")),ncol = 2,byrow = T)),c("start_ts","stop_ts"))
          start_ts          stop_ts
1 21/08/2014 23:07 21/08/2014 23:08
2 21/08/2014 23:29 21/08/2014 23:30
```

## FOR THE NEW EDIT:

```
 a = gsub("((.*?preparing){2})","\\1\n ",regex_text)
 b = read.table(text=gsub("(?<=preparing)(?=\\d+)","|",a,perl=T),sep="|",fill=T,h=F)
 d = sub("^(?:(?!CONTENT).)*$|(^.*)CONTENT.*$","\\1",as.matrix(b),perl=T)
 subset(data.frame(start_ts = d[,1],stop_ts = ifelse(d[,2]=="",d[,1],d[,2])),start_ts!="")
           start_ts          stop_ts
1  21/08/2014 22:58 21/08/2014 22:58
2  21/08/2014 23:07 21/08/2014 23:08
4  21/08/2014 23:29 21/08/2014 23:30
```

Comment: Ah yes, you are nearly there. However, I'd need it to work for more than two instances. We could have three or four sequence groups...

Comment: @Funtboy this works for all instances.. have you tried it? It will produce a dataframe with start and end columns for all instances..

Comment: Hi there, first of all, many thanks for your efforts. So, I added two events to the start of the string: 21/08/2014 22:58CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing21/08/2014 23:00EXE_IN.preparing  effectivley adding a new separate instance of CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing.   What I got back was nearly right, but not quite.

Comment: @Funtboy why do you keep doing things half way? No body is able to read your mind.. You added two events to the start of the string.. what then? Where? what do you expect out of that? You need to clearly show the two events you added, the new string and also the expected output from that string. Please read the how to ask a question section

Comment: Sorry, pressed return by accident.

Comment: You should show what you expect in that instant.. I am sorry to say I am not an angel to  know what you expect. Edit your question with the updated string and the expected output. Or rather ask a new question with the new string and the output you expect

Comment: @Funtboy you are supposed to edit YOUR QUESTION not MY SOLUTION

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178217/discussion-between-funtboy-and-onyambu).

Comment: Okay, I have edited my question to show the adjusted string and output. I have changed the regex_string in my original code to match (but not yours). Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list of matching instances you are looking for and create a loop

```
for (match in match_list){
#match as in your code
#add into db as in your code
}
```